# Оконные функции PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, база-данных

Столкнулся с необходимостью высчитать агрегатное значение от агрегатной функции (максимум от сумм частного, т.е max(sum(a*b))) для чего решил использовать имеющиеся в Postgres'е оконные функции (window functions).

Однако столкнулся с проблемой - максимальные значения "накапливаются" (да, я понимаю,что так оно и должно быть) , в то время как мне нужно вывести одно максимальное значение (т.е отбросить строки в которых значение < максимального). Как это сделать?

Сам текст запроса ниже:

```
SELECT customers.country,goods.category_id,
MAX(SUM(orders_details.quantity*goods.price)) OVER (PARTITION BY
customers.country ORDER BY goods.category_id)
FROM orders 
JOIN orders_details ON (orders_details.order_id = orders.id) 
INNER JOIN goods ON (orders_details.item_id = goods.id) 
INNER JOIN customers ON (customers.id = orders.customer_id) 
GROUP BY customers.country,goods.category_id
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: зачем тут оконные функции?  2 группировки и все

Comment: Ivan, спасибо. При помощи группировок и решил задачу. Изначально пошёл по неправильному пути. Спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял задачу, то можно сначала посчитать сумму (в разрезе стран), а потом получившееся сгруппировать и найти максимум.

```
SELECT  t.country,
        t.category_id,
        MAX(t.amount)
FROM   (
         SELECT customers.country,
                goods.category_id,
                SUM(orders_details.quantity*goods.price)
                OVER (PARTITION BY customers.country) amount
         FROM orders 
         JOIN orders_details ON (orders_details.order_id = orders.id) 
         INNER JOIN goods ON (orders_details.item_id = goods.id) 
         INNER JOIN customers ON (customers.id = orders.customer_id) 
       ) t
GROUP BY t.country,
         t.category_id;
```

Хотя, честно говоря, непонятно, зачем это может понадобиться.